# OpenCart cloning information

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, cart

i want to duplicate the information in admin because i want to insert in the footer new pages using the admin interface.

What should I do?
I've see i need to modify and clone this files: (pls tell me all the errors

```
admin/controller/catalog/information.php
admin/language/english/module/information.php
admin/model/catalog/information.php
admin/view/template/module/information.tpl

catalog/controller/information.php
catalog/model/catalog/information.php
catalog/view/theme/default/template/information/information.tpl
```

I need just to duplicate this to add Extra in footer and manage this like as Information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, copy those and rename (make sure the renaming is done properly). Modify to meet Your needs.

And do not forget to add a new menu entry in the administration, so modify these files as well:

- `admin/controller/common/header.php` - add new text and action link
- `admin/language/english/common/header.php` - add new entry translation
- `admin/view/template/common/header.tpl` - add new entry

That should be it. And of course, do not forget to modify the *footer* part of Your store ;-)